# HTML - Second IMG hover issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 semicircles stuck next to each other forming a circle. When I hover on the left semicircle, the right one lowers it's opacity (which is what is supposed to do) but when I hover on the right one, the opacity doesn't change at all.

HTML:

```
<div id="animation-components">
    <img src="leftball.svg" alt="" class="animation-item-01">
    <img src="rightball.svg" alt="" class="animation-item-02">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#animation-components {}

    .animation-item-01 {
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 240px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        transform: translate(631px,80px);
        height: 320px;
        transition: opacity ease 0.5s;
    }

    .animation-item-02 {
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 240px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        transform: translate(627px,80px);
        height: 320px;
        transition: opacity ease 0.5s;
    }

    .animation-item-01:hover + .animation-item-02{
        opacity: 50%;
    }

    .animation-item-02:hover + .animation-item-01{
        opacity: 50%;
    }
```

What can I alter to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can only select the **next** sibling with the adjacent sibling selector.

```css
.element-1 + .element-2 /* good */
.element-2 + .element-1 /* not so good */
```

Since `.animation-item-02` comes **after** `.animation-item-01`, there is no way to select the previous `.animation-item-01` from `.animation-item-02`

Doing the following will fix the issue:

```css
#animation-components:hover > div {
    opacity: 50%;
}
#animation-components > div:hover {
    opacity: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What can I do to make this work then? Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I edited my answer. Try out the solution and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Combinators can't be used to apply styles to elements before target element.

The adjacent sibling selector (+) will aply to all adjacent elements, not to it's opposite elements.

> CSS It's in the name: Cascading Style Sheets only supports styling in cascading direction, not up.

To achieve the desired, you can do the folowwing:

```css
#animation-components:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
}

#animation-components img:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation-components">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png/ff0000" alt="" class="animation-item-01">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png/ff0000" alt="" class="animation-item-02">
</div>
```

Comment: This worked out. Thank you so much. I apparently had to change my DIV size and location as well because it didnt match with the components.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be me but I find it heaps easier to throw in just a little bit of javascript and avoid messy css combinators. Heres my fix, script goes anywhere in your html file, I put it after the closing body tag.

```js
<script>
    function fadeOut(obj) {
        document.getElementById(obj).style.animationName = "fadeOut";
    }
    function fadeIn(obj) {
        document.getElementById(obj).style.animationName = "fadeIn";
    }
</script>
```

```css
#item1 {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 240px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    transform: translate(631px,80px);
    height: 320px;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#item2 {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 240px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    transform: translate(627px,80px);
    height: 320px;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    0%{opacity: 1;}
    100%{opacity: 0.5;}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0%{opacity: 0.5;}
    100%{opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div id="animation-components">
        <img src="leftball.svg" alt="" id="item1" onmouseover="fadeOut('item1')" onmouseout="fadeIn('item1')">
        <img src="rightball.svg" alt="" id="item2" onmouseover="fadeOut('item2')" onmouseout="fadeIn('item2')">
</div>
```

Also its just a me thing, but you have class attributes where id attributes should be. If your applying seperate styles to two completely seperate elements its a good idea to use id, but if your applying same style to two elements

Comment: I just started learning html and css 4 days ago but thanks anyways! Once I learn JavaScript I'll make sure to try this